# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView Java 8 android

Tags: android, java-8, android-navigationview

I have a problem with NavigationView. It works perfect in debug mode, but after release build it does not work :( I only update gradle version and add java 8 support. A 1-2 month ago this project works after release build. So it is a problem with gradle, or java 8, proguard, or what?

UPDATE: after removing java 8 release build work

Error message

```
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.*.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                 at com.spinne.smsparser3.b.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.spinne.smsparser3.b.g.c.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                 at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
                                                 at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
                                                 at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                 at com.spinne.smsparser3.b.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.spinne.smsparser3.b.g.c.onCreateView(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
                                                 at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                 at com.spinne.smsparser3.b.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.spinne.smsparser3.b.g.c.onCreateView(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
                                                 at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                 at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(Unknown Source)
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                 at com.spinne.smsparser3.b.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.spinne.smsparser3.b.g.c.onCreateView(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
                                                 at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                 at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                 at com.spinne.smsparser3.b.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.spinne.smsparser3.b.g.c.onCreateView(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
                                                 at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                 at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                 at com.spinne.smsparser3.b.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.spinne.smsparser3.b.g.c.onCreateView(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
                                                 at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
                                                 at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.*"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 17
    versionName '3.3.0'

    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('../AppKeys.keystore')
        storePassword ''
        keyAlias 'appkey'
        keyPassword ''
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:+'
}
```

Proguard

```
# Gson
-keep public class com.google.gson
-keep class com.someapp.android.models.ChatModel { *; }
-keep class com.someapp.android.models.FeedModel { *; }

# Annotations and signatures
-keepattributes Signature

# android support library
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager { *; }

# Other
-dontwarn com.github.mikephil.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
```

Activity

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/menu_content_left"
        style="@style/BaseMenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/left_menu_item"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/left_menu_item"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: There is a similar issue already posted in the Android issue tracker. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218917&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened you can star this to see its progress.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for quick fix while google release the future version, add this to your proguard file :

```
# android support library
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator { *; }
```